# Intellij-IDEA путает версию Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IDEA возвращает вот такую ошибку:

Error:(13, 12) java: try-with-resources is not supported in -source **1.5**
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable try-with-resources)

Хотя в свойствах проекта и в Project SDK и в language level стоит **11** версия.

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: у вас не мавен проект случаем? в какой момент ошибка выдается?

Comment: Если используете `maven-compiler-plugin`, то возможно там у вас опция `maven.compiler.source` в `pom.xml` равна `1.5`

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, да, maven, ошибка появляется после Build > Build Project

Comment: Там еще на вкладке modules есть опция lnaguage level

Comment: комментарий господина iksuy проверяли?)

Comment: @Serhii Dikobrazko, Спасибо большое, это сработало.

Comment: @Stranger in the Q у меня в pom.xml нет такой строчки "maven.compiler.source". Я не там ищу?

Comment: @АндрейСеменютенко maven compiler plugin совершенно не обязателен к использованию в паре с idea, но мог бы быть :)

Comment: @АндрейСеменютенко да не за что (:

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - проверь еще "Project structure-Modules-Language level"

Answer (score 0):

IDEA при работе с maven-проектами информацию о версии JDK берёт из pom.xml. Если она не задана, то используется 1.5. Задать версию JDK можно двумя способами:

1. Указав версию в `properties`:

   ```
   <project>
       [...]
       <properties>
           <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
           <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
       </properties>
       [...]
   </project>
   ```
2. Указав настройки плагина `maven-compiler-builder`:

   ```
   <project>
     [...]
     <build>
       [...]
       <plugins>
         <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.8.0</version>
           <configuration>
             <source>11</source>
             <target>11</target>
           </configuration>
         </plugin>
       </plugins>
       [...]
     </build>
     [...]
   </project>
   ```

[Документация плагина](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

Answer (score -1):

На на Саму запись только для чтения, прям открытом проекте нажать правой кнопкой мыши появляется шоу context actions showcontex axon нажать, далее выбрать либо run main.main, либо debug....и ап, все работает пишем...

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь как-то более явно излагать свои мысли. для внесения исправлений нажмите [edit]

Answer (score -1):

Ещё вариант при создании проекта нажать на сам проект и убрать галочку с запись чтения скобочках на английском конечно

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь как-то более явно излагать свои мысли. для внесения исправлений нажмите [edit]